# Problem with scanf() on mac

Tags: c, macos, scanf

I compile a C library on mac os x. When I typed the input and after printing on the screen the data I don't see something.

```
char *path = NULL;
peerdisplay = "Bob";
printf("Insert the full 'To' path: ");
scanf(" %a[^\n]", &path);
printf("A path: %s \n", &path);
```

When I replace the %a to %s, the printing ok, but after the running I have a segmentation error.
I like to running such as script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

%a is gnu-specific non-standard extension to scanf grabs. What says your OS X manpages about it ?

> The GNU C library supports a non-standard extension  that  causes  the
>         library  to dynamically allocate a string of sufficient size for input
>         strings for the %s and %a[range] conversion specifiers.  To  make  use
>         of  this  feature,  specify  a  as  a  length  modifier  (thus  %as or
>         %a[range]).  The caller must free(3) the returned string

^is that your intent ?

in that case, be aware that

> The `a` modifier is not available if the program is  compiled  with  gcc
>         -std=c99  or  gcc  -D_ISOC99_SOURCE (unless _GNU_SOURCE is also speci-
>         fied), in which case the a is interpreted as a specifier for floating-
>         point numbers (see above).

Answer (score 2):

You need to allocate memory for path.  It needs to be enough memory for whatever bytes will be entered, plus the NULL terminating byte.

Answer (score 1):

Your `path` is a null pointer, make it point to some allocated memory large enough to hold the string to be read and the terminating `null` char.

You should not be passing address of `path` to `scanf` and `printf`, instead pass `path` itself.

Since you are scanning a string use `%s` instead of `%a`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you pass a null into scanf as you're doing here, you're basically telling the c library to copy whatever string is entered into null space (aka the first page of memory, usually protected against writing for just this reason).  Secondly, %a is supposed to match a floating point number, not a string.  Third, it might be a good idea to actually read the documentation for a library function before you start calling it.